# Inline class which extends a type parameter

Tags: java, generics, ormlite

I want to write a quick and dirty helper class which can quickly save my objects. Therefore I'm using OrmLite.

I don't want to add annotations on my classes, so I try to add a wrapper on the fly, without any bytecode-libs.

```
<T> void save(T o) {
    @DatabaseTable
    class wrap extends T {
        @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
        public Long id;
    }

    try {
        Dao<T, Long> d = (Dao<T, Long>) getClassDao(o.getClass());
        TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(connectionSource, o.getClass());
        d.createOrUpdate(o);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

The problem is `class wrap extends T` - why is it not possible to extend `T`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a weird but interesting question! It's tricky to give an exact and exhaustive answer. There are probably a lot of different reasons, but I think the following one is the most important:

**Only one version of `save` will ever be generated by the compiler.** For `class wrap extends T` to work the parameter `T` would have to be a different concrete classes for every use of `save` with a different type, but that is not how generics work. `save` is compiled only one time, and inside `save` `T` is a type parameter, not a concrete type. (This is somewhat related to, but different from type erasure, see below.)

*Another* reason is [**type erasure**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Generic types in Java is something that only exists at *compile time*. A class in Java on the other hand *has a runtime representation* (in contrast to, for example, C++). So there is no possibility that the runtime representation of a class could be generated from the compile-time-only construct that a generic type is.

Answer (score 2):

`<T>` is a generic type, not a real class. A generic type is a compile time concept, it get erased at runtime, while a class is a runtime stuff and it does have corresponding bytecode. You can't declare a sub class of generic type `<T>` because compiler has no idea what that super class is

Answer (score 1):

Because T could be final. Final classes cannot be extended.

At least this is a logical reason that prohibits extending a generic type. The technical background is explained in other answers.

Comment: can i declare T as non-final?

Comment: Its' true, but it's not about beeing final. It's about beeing *generic*. 'T' could be any class at runtime. But `wrap` is only compiled once, at compile time. See answer by @Lii